# How to execute a non-blocking script in python and get its return code?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am trying to execute a non-blocking bash script from python and to get its return code. Here is my function so far:

```
def run_bash_script(script_fullname, logfile):
    my_cmd = ". " + script_fullname + " >" + logfile +" 2>&1"
    p = subprocess.Popen(my_cmd, shell=True)
    os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)
    print(p.returncode)
```

As you can see, all the output is redirected into a log file, which I can monitor while the bash process is running.

However, the last command just returns 'None' instead of a useful exit code.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `p.wait()` rather than `os.waitpid()`. `os.waitpid()` is a low level api and it knows nothing about the `Popen` object so it could not touch `p`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that was exactly what I needed!